# Removing rows based on a string in R

Tags: r

My dataset has two columns that look like below.

```
Digits  Age
(C)     25
(DL)    30
(E)     40
(R)     45
(N)     50
```

I want to remove all the rows where column value in `Digits` is not equal to `(C)` or `(DL)`.

Can this be achieved?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
myDf <- data.frame(Digits = c("C","DL","E","R","N"), Age = c(25,30,40,45,50))
newDf <- myDf[myDf$Digits == "C" | myDf$Digits == "DL", ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df<-read.table(text="Digits  Age
              (C)     25
              (DL)    30
              (E)     40
              (R)     45
              (N)     50", stringsAsFactors=F,h=T)
dfnew<-df[which(df$Digits %in% c("(C)","(DL)")),]
```

Result:

```
  Digits Age
1    (C)  25
2   (DL)  30
```

Comment: Thank you so much all.  All of your approaches work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  Digits = c("(C)", "(DL)", "(E)", "(R)", "(N)"),
  Age = c(25L, 30L, 40L, 45L, 50L)
)

df %>% filter(!Digits %in% c("(C)", "(DL)"))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Digits   Age
#>    <chr> <int>
#> 1    (E)    40
#> 2    (R)    45
#> 3    (N)    50
```